# decision to go with Angularjs 1.x or Angularjs 2.0 in middle of development

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have been using Angularjs in my application since a year and upgraded version since 1.2 to 1.4. As a part of angularjs version, i observed lot of improvement with custom templates, performance features.
Last week, I saw AngularJS 2 alpha version [enter link description here](https://angular.io/download/)
and went through videos release, its seem some promising but they shows RIP for (controller, scope, module ) whole framework and it way to rewrite whole framework. I like that Angularjs 2.0 framework build on component but my concern or worries different and raise fellow queries.

1. As i am in middle of development phase, completed one main module in Angularjs 1.4 and now going for phase 2, how to proceed further development.
2. How Hybrid development trustworthy with Angularjs 1.4 and Angularjs 2.0
3. Is starting with development with Alpha/Beta version will be right decision or stick to Angularjs 1.4 only.
4. As a developer, how should i convience to my management at this stage to shift from Angularjs 1.4 to Angularjs 2.0 as we already completed phase 1 in v1.4.

Appreciate feedback to think now to move forward with AngularJS.

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a subjective matter to me, but here is my thoughts.

1. I would stick to 1.4 until AngularJS 2.0 is released, that is, until it goes out of Alfa/Beta releases. When working on a larger project stating out on a completely new way of doing things (components) furthermore doing it before most of the bug fixes are done is to risky for me.
2. Referencing [this AngularJS blog post](http://angularjs.blogspot.dk/2015/08/angular-1-and-angular-2-coexistence.html) about AngularJS migration and some keynote from ngConf that I can't find, your AngularJS 1.4 code is valid in 2.0. This means you can rewrite the parts that are 1.4 whenever your doing the move to 2.0 step by step.
3. Same arguments as 1. I'd stick to 1.4 until the final release of 2.0
4. You should not for now. ;) When you get the final 2.0 release and understand how much time (money) it will take to rewrite the old parts you can talk to the management if they are willing to go on this path. The arguments them self, I'm sure, are clear already as of performance etc.